# Multiple definition of error - CodeBlocks

Tags: c, codeblocks

I have the the following files in my project:

```
table.h - signatures of methods used in link.c and hash.c
link.c - implements ALL methods in table.h
hash.c - implements ALL methods in table.h
test.c - unit tests for link.c and hash.c
```

I've used guards in my header file. Both link.c and hash.c have different implementations of the same set of methods.

When I build and run my project, I get errors thrown for each method which says: "multiple definition of "

I've tried declaring the methods extern, it does not solve the issue.

table.h

```
#ifndef TABLE_H_INCLUDED
#define TABLE_H_INCLUDED

typedef struct Table *Table_t;

Table_t Table_new(void);

void Table_free(Table_t oTable);

int Table_getLength(Table_t oTable);

int SymTable_put(SymTable_t oSymTable,
                 const char *pcKey,
                 const void *pvValue);

void *Table_get(Table_t oTable,
                   const char *key);

int Table_contains(Table_t oTable,
                      const char *key);


void *Table_remove(Table_t oTable,
                    const char *key);


void *Table_replace(Table_t oTable,
                       const char *key,
                       const void *value);
#undef TABLE_H_INCLUDED
#endif
```

Error log:

obj\Debug\table_link.o||In function `Table_new':|

E:\symbolTableProject\table_link.c|33|multiple definition of `Table_new'|

obj\Debug\table_hash.o:E:\symbolTableProject\table_hash.c|36|first defined here|

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Can you include the files as well?

Comment: The important file to show us is the header file. You must define some symbol (which one we don't know since you don't show us the complete and unedited error output) in the header file, not only declaring it. Please *edit your question* to include the header file and the complete and unedited error log. Could also be good to show us the outline of the `test.c` file.

Comment: Also, do *both* the `link.c` and `hash.c` source files define the same functions?

Comment: As I answered, you couldn't implement a function twice in your code. Pick one between `hash.c` and `link.c`.

Comment: You should *not* undefine the header inclusion guard macro, that actually defeats the purpose of having include guards.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the key point is

```
link.c - implements ALL methods in table.h
hash.c - implements ALL methods in table.h
```

Those files could not be linked to the same output: I mean, each function must be implemented unique.

You could implement all functions in a single/multiple `c` file/s and than `#include "table.h"` in files where functions are used. The important thing is that each function must be implemented 1 time only in source files.